# Open an Excel Addin in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, excel-addins

I inherited a C# windows application that builds a big spreadsheet to display to the user.  An enhancement is to add an existing Excel Add-in to this spreadsheet.  I have been trying to add the Add-in once the spreadsheet has been completed in the code like this:

```
            excelApp.Visible = true;
            // trying to add the Add-in
            string workBookPath = @"C:\AddinIWasGiven.xls";
            Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workBookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

Whenever I do this, I get this error:
    "Cannot open Microsoft Excel Add-In for editing. Please edit the source document instead".  I am unsure why I am getting this error.  I do see that excelWorkbook comes back as "C:\AddinIWasGiven.xls", but I read that could be how the debugger is showing it.  I'm new to Add-ins and C#.  Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

With some help and trial and error, I found that this worked:

string workBookPath = @"C:\Addin.xla";
Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workBookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", false, false, 0, true, false, false);

Comment: It is indeed a `.xls` file? It seems that it is an add-in converted to a workbook. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156943/en-us Add-in files used to have `.xla` extension.

Comment: It is an .xls file.  I was wondering if that was the problem.

Comment: It might be your problem, try to save it as `*.xlam` file, IsAddin property should be `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @VDohnal.  I changed the file to .xla and had to set the editable flag in the Open function to false.  That allowed the add-in to be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-in files should have `.xla` or `.xlam` extension. Set `Workbook.IsAddin=true` by saving the `.xls` file as Excel add-in `.xlam`